# Does Mono/Flux have operators like Peek / IfPresent from the Stream / Optional API?

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-webflux, project-reactor

As title says, was wondering if, when working with Mono/Flux, are there any equivalent (or similar) operators to peek and ifPresent from the Java Stream API.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. Fixed the title.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Flux#hasElement`:

> Emit a single boolean true if any of the elements of this Flux sequence is equal to the provided value. The implementation uses short-circuit logic and completes with true if an element matches the value.

```
Mono<Boolean> ifPresent = Flux.<Ob>just(...)
        .hasElement(value); // similar to ifPresent
```

`Flux#doOnNext`:

> Add behavior (side-effect) triggered when the Flux emits an item.

```
Flux<Ob> flux = Flux.<Ob>just()
        .doOnNext(i -> {}); // similar to peek
```

Comment: I guess so but if you want to get an `Optional` you can do something like `Flux...filter(something)...next().blockOptional()`

Comment: @MichaelBerry damsen was looking for an exact duplicate. I don't know what to say ;)